# Add custom tinymce initial configuration option

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

I want to add this `customOption: ""` as an option on `tinymce.init`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    customOption: "",
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen",
        "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media",
        "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks",
    ]
});
</script>
```

tinymce version: 6.7.0

Comment: After little digging on the tinymce documentation I found: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/apis/tinymce.editoroptions/